# gnatlink fails under new Ubuntu version

Tags: ada, ubuntu-12.10

I installed a new version of Ubuntu (12.10, upgraded from 12.04) and now I can not link.  This is true even for a simple "Hello_World.adb" program:

```
gnatlink hello_world
/usr/gnat/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/ld: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gnatlink: error when calling /usr/gnat/bin/gcc
```

I have seen a number of "fixes" in various forums, but they don't seem to work with gnat:  I presume this has to do with gnat's own command line construction.  I have tried various constructs myself to no avail.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

---

NEW INFO:  I created an Oracle "virtual box" running Ubuntu 12.04, installed the latest "libre" GNAT GPL, and it appears to work just fine.  Apparently, the problem has something to do with the Ubuntu 12.10 release.  I have 12.10 running on both a physical machine and a VM:  Both cause GNAT GPL to fail.  fwiw

## I will consider this question closed.  Thanks to everyone for their ideas and suggestions!

New, new info:  I had neglected to set the PATH variable, so that the path to the GNAT binaries was at the end of the string.  Apparentlhy this is what allowed me to link.  When I took GNAT GPL's suggestion to place the binary path at the beginning of the string, the link stopped working!  Screwy!  Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: I am using the latest libre gnatgpl for x86 linux.  32-bits.

Comment: `gnatmake` works; I don't know whether that would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Keith, but gnatmake fails with the same error message + the additional message 'gnatmake: ***link failed.'

Comment: Hmm, it works for me in Ubuntu 12.10 (actually Xubuntu, installed from CD, not upgraded). Take a look at https://gist.github.com/4042215

Comment: Don't know whether it makes any difference, but you are using an earlier version of GNATMAKE.  Mine says, 'GNATMAKE GPL 2012 (20120509)'

Comment: Downloaded and installed GNAT GPL from 2010 (20100603) and still get the same error message.  This seems to be something strange with Ubuntu.  The "missing" file (crt1.o) does show up in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/.  This must not be where ld is expecting it to be.  Or something.  I am really baffled by all this.

Comment: Did you install GNAT from the Ubuntu repositories, using `apt-get` or something similar, or did you install it from some other source?

Comment: Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install gnat`; you might also need to install `gnat-doc` and `gnat-gps`. No idea why the version you downloaded isn't working (I haven't tried it), but the version I installed from the Ubuntu repositories works for me.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like the errors I get on Windows when the compiler isn't installed right (some things are pointing at an old version, some at a new version).

Answer (score 1):

Check file-permissions & file-paths. *nix has a really fragile permission-systems, and sometimes things work dependent on actual directories vs symlinked directories.

Or just migrate to Windows, I've had a total of ONE problem with file-permissions... and it was on a *nix subsystem (cygwin, IIRC).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Shark8.  In case there was a permissions issue, I set myself to superuser, but the problem persists.  I would rather be on Windows, but I need to use Posix, and the Florist on Windows is very incomplete, last time I checked.  I will try installing an earlier version in a virtualbox on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Debian with, it seems, a 64-bit GNAT GPL 2012. I can get `gnatmake` to tell me what command line is sent to the system linker by using the `-largs -Wl,-v` flags:

```
$ gnatmake -f hello.adb -largs -Wl,-v
gcc -c hello.adb
gnatbind -x hello.ali
gnatlink hello.ali -Wl,-v
collect2 version 4.5.4 20120510 for GNAT GPL 2012 (20120509) (x86-64 Linux/ELF)
/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/ld --eh-frame-hdr -m
elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o hello
/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crti.o
/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/crtbegin.o
-L./ -L/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/adalib/
-L/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4
-L/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/../lib/gcc
-L/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/../../../../lib64
-L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64
-L/opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/../../..
b~hello.o ./hello.o -v /opt/gnat-gpl-2012/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/adalib/libgnat.a
-lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh /opt/gnat-gpl-2012/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.4/crtend.o
/usr/lib/../lib64/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.20
```

which shows it's picking up `crt1.o` (and others) from /usr/lib64 (YMMV).

I wonder whether you need to (re)install the Ubuntu C compiler? (I think it was `sudo apt-get build-essentials`).

On the other hand, using `dpkg --search` (to find which installed package installed a particular file) suggests that maybe you just need package `libc`, or perhaps `libc-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've had this problem, it has usually been a manifestation of the "multi-lib problem" newer versions of Debian and now Ubuntu are moving their libraries around, so that you can build e.g. 32-bit and 64-bit executables  (or cross-compile for Windows or Arduino!) on the same machine ...

So on my machine, I can find crt1.o at

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

and if I issue the command line

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

before running Gnatmake, it solves the problem.
As it is the linker (ld) that fails, you might want to try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

if LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work

If that's it, there are other ways to solve the problem, 
like ways to fiddle library paths in your .bashrc script...

Comment: Should have mentioned, if you are on a 32-bit machine, your LIBRARY_PATH setting will be different. You'll need to find where crt1.0 lives in your Ubuntu 12.10 installation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone.  I have tried all the above suggestions and have tried every combination of GPS, previously working Ubuntu version, and hard and virtual machines without success.

I now am successfully pursuing a (very) limited Windows Posix (wposix) version using pipes, since that is all that is implemented in the wposix product.  I wanted to use shared memory and messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the only solution that I could find was to run following command as superuser:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64
```